# Reset Azure B2C Tenant MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to access aB2C tenant however my phone had a meltdown a few months ago and I lost the MS Authenticator account.  How can I reset the tenant to enable MFA access again?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a rest API service configured with admin privileges, generate a new admin account to create a backdoor to login to your tenant
2. Most B2C tenants are created with a corp account (O365), contact your IT to reset your phone MFA options - this is only applicable if the MFA is being applied from the resource tenant and not the B2C tenant
3. If you used a personal Microsoft Account and the MFA is applied to this account, contact Microsoft support: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/account-recovery-lost-pw-and-mfa/558766e2-b8a9-48aa-b0af-af9016972ed0

Comment: Thanks but we haven't configured any REST APIs and the service desk have advised they can't reset my MFA because it was created in a VS subscription they don't have access to and it's a corporate account, not a MS account.

Comment: Where is the MFA policy being applied? It's not clear in your post. Is it a dedicated Azure AD test environment that was created by your corp account? If a CA policy has been applied outside scope of your corp account then, your next step is a MSFT support case. Best practice is to create a break glass account (for next time). In some cases, they verify ownership using domain (if you have verified a domain). Many cases there are multiple MFA options unless again, you turned this off too.